# Отключение проверки seo url

Tags: php, opencart

Имеются повторяющиеся подкатегории, к примеру:
`Samsung - комплектующие`
`LG - комплектующие`
т.е. в данном случае повторяются подкатегории `комплектующие`
при создании таких подкатегорий, seo url которых `komplektujushhie`, выдаётся ошибка: `Этот SEO keyword уже используется!`
ocstore 2.3
в файле `admin/controller/catalog/category.php` отключил часть кода, отвечающую за валидацию поля, в котором прописывается `seo url` - `keyword`, а именно:

```
    if (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['keyword']) > 0) {
        $this->load->model('catalog/url_alias');

        $url_alias_info = $this->model_catalog_url_alias->getUrlAlias($this->request->post['keyword']);

        if ($url_alias_info && isset($this->request->get['category_id']) && $url_alias_info['query'] != 'category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id']) {
            $this->error['keyword'] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_keyword'));
        }

        if ($url_alias_info && !isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
            $this->error['keyword'] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_keyword'));
        }
    }
```

теперь повторяющие подкатегории проходят валидацию, но на фронтенде, при открытии такой подкатегории, к примеру `/samsung/komplektujushhie`, эта страница открывается нормально,
но если открыть `/lg/komplektujushhie`, то url выглядит примерно так: `/index.php?route=product/category&path=...`, т.е. `seo url` не срабатывает.
Подскажите, как исправить данную проблему, при том, что подкатегория `комплектующие` в разных категориях может быть на разных уровнях вложенности

Answer (score 1):

В стандартном опенкарт этого сделать невозможно.
Там все url хранятся в одной таблице и один Url может соответствовать только одной сущности. В данном случае категории. И когда вы сохраняете одну катгеорию с этим url, она перезаписывает данные другой.
Чтобы сделать так, как хотите вы, надо переделывать работу опенкарт с url. Нпр хранить в категориях это url и переделать скрипт, который по url ищет категорию и наоборот формирует url с учетом этих изменений.